# Count every time an object if displayed/accessed

Tags: python, django

Sorry if my headline wasn't explicit enough.

I'm trying to develop a marketing tool that track every single page of my project. So I'm using InfluxDB along PostgreSQL. I am able to track pages (or clicks) but not the "views".

Let me explain:

If I have a 10 items in the listing. I want to track which item has been displayed on which page. Example: Item B was displayed on page 2; Item C was displayed on page 1.

I was planing on looping through the list but I don't like this solution because I have to loop twice: one for tracking, one for display the item.
So I'm looking for a cleaner solution but I'm out of ideas. What would you do?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

Here are the ideas I found from most favorable to least favorable:

1. create template_tag to track view per object
2. loop through the list before looping again for display
3. use javascript with specific class name to track object

Answer (score 0):

Maybe  can you add a field in your object:

**models.py**

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    ...
    viewed: models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Number of views', blank=True, default=0)
```

and then, in your all your views displaying the object:

**views.py**

```
def myView(request):
    object = myModel.objects.get(id=id)
    object.viewed += 1
    object.save()
```

Comment: No because I plan to set the stats into another table. Beside it means I have to loop through every object to increment the counter and write into the database to save it which is not ideal. But thanks for the suggestion.